# exchange javaScript with selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm trying to exchange the javaScript functionality of a webpage using selenium (for java with firefox geckodriver if that matters).

consider the following webpage

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV id="time">Time</DIV>
</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
    !function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = new Date();
        }, 500);
    }();
</SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

now after opening it with selenium I'm using `JavascriptExecutor` to remove the `<SCRIPT>` part.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script');" +
    "for(var i = (r.length - 1); i >=0; i--){" +
    "   r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]);" +
    "}");
```

and now I'm waiting for 2sec and add a new `<SCRIPT>` element.

```
Thread.sleep(2000);

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "var newScript = document.createElement(\"SCRIPT\");" +
    "newScript.innerHTML = \"document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'NEW SCRIPT IS RUNNING';\";" +             
    "document.body.appendChild(newScript);");
```

It seams to work but the old script is still running and updates the `<DIV>` tag with the current time. So I'm looking for something to stop the active javaScript threads. Or a possibility to tell selenium to 'soft' reload the page with the changed DOM tree.

Comment: Yes, removing the script from the DOM won't clear the interval. Without the interval id you won't be able to clear it, but I suppose you could try to guess it. Or you could try to intercept the response and change it.

Comment: I'm aware of how to clear the interval. This is just a demo of what I want to achieve. In fact I'm looking for a more general approach. In the real use case of what I'm trying to do here I don't know what the original javascript is doing. I just want to kill its runtime and inject my own.

Comment: I would guess that stripping the script tags from the response is the only way to do that.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks for the very good hint. thats really a good thought I've not come up to and it fully solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @pguardiario if've implemented a fully working solution. I use [browserMob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) to intercept the response to the webpage request. Then remove all `<SCRIPT>` Tags in the response and pass the modified HTML to the selenium web driver that can now inject its own JavaScript.

```
String website = "http://SOME_WEB_PAGE.com";

// proxy object
BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();

// create an response filter
proxy.addResponseFilter(new ResponseFilter() {
    @Override
    public void filterResponse(HttpResponse response, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo) {
        // if this is a response to the webpage request
        if(messageInfo.getUrl().equals(website)){
            // parse result with JSOUP and delete all <SCRIPT> Tags
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(contents.getTextContents());                     
            for(Element e : doc.select("script")) e.remove();                       
            contents.setTextContents(doc.html());
        }
    }
});

// start the proxy and put in as firefox option
proxy.start(0);
Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);            
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
FirefoxOptions op = new FirefoxOptions();
op.merge(dc);

// start the selenium web driver and open webpage that should not have any <SCRIPT> Tags now
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(op);                       
driver.get(website);            
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// inject your own javaScript
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "var newScript = document.createElement(\"SCRIPT\");" +
    "newScript.innerHTML = \"document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'NEW SCRIPT IS RUNNING';\";" +             
    "document.body.appendChild(newScript);");
```